# Нужен визуальный компонент Delphi, аналог отображения дефрагментации диска в старых версиях Windows

Tags: delphi, компоненты

*Требования*

Описание: Нужен визуальный компонент, который **отображает в окне упорядоченное количество элементов в виде цветных прямоугольников**

Количество элементов: 1024 макс, линейное с лева на право заполнение до конца видимой области, далее с новой строки

У каждого элемента: программно возможность изменения позиции в списке и цвета, всплывающая подсказка, popup меню

Как бонус: масштабирование и прокрутка видимой области отображения

Вид: Аналог отображения дефрагментации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: *Таких компонентов не знаю, может подскажете если есть? А если нет, то посоветуйте как написать?*

= Windows 10 Ent 1607, Embarcadero Delphi 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDrawGrid + простенькое хранилище информации в списке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ar, ac: Integer;
begin
  TDrawGrid(Sender).MouseToCell(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y, ac, ar);
  PopupMenu1.Items[0].Caption := Format('%d %d', [ar, ac]);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  c: TCanvas;
begin
  c := TDrawGrid(Sender).Canvas;
  if ARow > 3 then
    c.Brush.Color := clWindow
  else
    c.Brush.Color := Random($1000000);
  Rect.Inflate(-2, -2);
  c.FillRect(Rect);
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. "Очевидно же" (фильм Платформа, 2019 (с)) :) Это понятно. Буду очень признателен куску кода, любому, который делает примерно то же самое, хотя бы частично или просто отрисовку граф. объектов. Или ссылкам где почитать\посмотреть примерные вещи. +Кстати, а Вы уверены, что DG может рисовать такие квадратики со свойствами объекта и взаимодействием типа у каждого всплывающее меню? Прогерством на D давно не занимался, но вроде такая штука не возможна раньше была? Или что-то поменялось?

Comment: Да года с девяносто пятого такая штука была возможна. Грид просто предоставляет место в виде разграфленной решетки, а программист рисует, что хочет. Пример набросал.

Comment: 2 Mbo. Большое спасибо! Ваш пример (ответ) - решение задачи. Еще мелкий вопрос, уже не имеющий отношения к основному вопросу: вот в скринах в вопросе - там ммм.. такие как бы "выпуклые" красивые квадратики - это тоже результат отрисовки или туда проецируются картинки из ресурсов, как считаете? Если не сложно ткните носом (подобные вопросы\ссылки, проч), как такое реализовать? Про DG все слова назад беру. Я по Вашей подсказке смог сделать это: https://d.radikal.ru/d33/2004/75/733356f752a3.png , вот как раз сюда пришел, чтобы дальше получить ответы. А тут все готово. Очень благодарен.

Comment: Нужно вручную нарисовать выпуклые квадратики нужного цвета заранее, а при работе копировать кусочек соответствующего цвета в нужное место. Есть функция DrawEdge, однако она произвольный цвет не рисует, только btnface.

Comment: @MBo `Rect.Offset(2, 2);` и две следующие команды заменяются одной: `Rect.Inflate(-2, -2);` если что.

Comment: @Alekcvp Во, спасибо, я знал, что метод такой есть, а название не вспомнил

Comment: Большое спасибо, вопрос закрыт

Comment: Около 50 человек отписали с др. форумов, что Ваше решение им помогло. Еще раз большое спасибо, жаль еще + не могу поставить.